# Error occured when trying to create a controller of type ' .. '. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a common project and pulled this code from Gitlab. I had to develop the Login API for the same. I have developed the API as a service and injected it into the Authenticate controller.

While calling the controller from both browser and Postman, I am getting an error

> Error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'AuthenticateController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameter less public constructor

and a few more errors related to AutoFac. I haven't worked with AutoFac before so it's kinda tough for me to understand what the other errors mean. I am attaching the Stack trace of the error.

Stack trace of error:

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'AuthenticateController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace> at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()</StackTrace>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>An exception was thrown while activating Capstone2.API.AuthenticateController.</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace> at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next) in /_/src/Autofac/Core/Resolving/Middleware/ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.cs:line 48 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt) in /_/src/Autofac/Core/Resolving/Pipeline/ResolvePipelineBuilder.cs:line 281 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt) in /_/src/Autofac/Core/Resolving/Pipeline/ResolvePipelineBuilder.cs:line 281 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.SharingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next) in /_/src/Autofac/Core/Resolving/Middleware/SharingMiddleware.cs:line 58 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt) in /_/src/Autofac/Core/Resolving/Pipeline/ResolvePipelineBuilder.cs:line 281 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt) in /_/src/Autofac/Core/Resolving/Pipeline/ResolvePipelineBuilder.cs:line 281 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next) in /_/src/Autofac/Core/Resolving/Middleware/CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware.cs:line 94 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt) in /_/src/Autofac/Core/Resolving/Pipeline/ResolvePipelineBuilder.cs:line 281 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, ResolveRequest request) in /_/src/Autofac/Core/Resolving/ResolveOperation.cs:line 150 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ExecuteOperation(ResolveRequest request) in /_/src/Autofac/Core/Resolving/ResolveOperation.cs:line 207 at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(ResolveRequest request) in /_/src/Autofac/Core/Lifetime/LifetimeScope.cs:line 290 at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) in /_/src/Autofac/ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 1113 at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in /_/src/Autofac/ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 814 at Autofac.Integration.WebApi.AutofacWebApiDependencyScope.GetService(Type serviceType) in C:\projects\autofac-webapi\src\Autofac.Integration.WebApi\AutofacWebApiDependencyScope.cs:line 76 at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)</StackTrace>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Capstone2.API.AuthenticateController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter 'Capstone2.Entities.Login login' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Capstone2.Service.Interfaces.ILoginService, Capstone2.Entities.Login)'.</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace> at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.GetAllBindings(ConstructorBinder[] availableConstructors, IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in /_/src/Autofac/Core/Activators/Reflection/ReflectionActivator.cs:line 175 at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in /_/src/Autofac/Core/Activators/Reflection/ReflectionActivator.cs:line 134 at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.<ConfigurePipeline>b__11_0(ResolveRequestContext ctxt, Action`1 next) in /_/src/Autofac/Core/Activators/Reflection/ReflectionActivator.cs:line 104 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt) in /_/src/Autofac/Core/Resolving/Pipeline/ResolvePipelineBuilder.cs:line 281 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.DisposalTrackingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next) in /_/src/Autofac/Core/Resolving/Middleware/DisposalTrackingMiddleware.cs:line 32 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt) in /_/src/Autofac/Core/Resolving/Pipeline/ResolvePipelineBuilder.cs:line 281 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next) in /_/src/Autofac/Core/Resolving/Middleware/ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.cs:line 36</StackTrace>
</InnerException>
</InnerException>
</Error>
```

Controller code:

```
public class AuthenticateController : BaseApiUnitOfWorkAndLogController
{
    private readonly ILoginService _loginService;
    private readonly Login _login;

    public AuthenticateController(ILoginService loginService, Login login)
    {
       _loginService = loginService;
        _login = login;
    }

    public Auth_Token Login()
    {
        return _loginService.UserLogin(_login);
    }
}
```

Login service code:

```
public class LoginService : ILoginService
{
    private Capstone2Context _context;

    public LoginService(Capstone2Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public Auth_Token UserLogin(Login login)
    {
        var user = _context.Logins.Where(i => i.LoginEmail == login.LoginEmail && i.Password == login.Password);

        if (user != null)
        {
            Implementation Details
        }
        else
        {
            Implementation Details
        }
        _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

`ILogin` interface:

```
public interface ILoginService
{
    Auth_Token UserLogin(Login login);
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class Capstone2Context : DbContext
{
    public Capstone2Context()
        : base("Name=Capstone2Context")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Capstone2Context>(null);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }

    public DbSet<Login> Logins { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Auth_Token> Auth_Tokens { get; set; }
    public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }
}
```

Any help regarding solving this will be highly appreciated. Please excuse me if the question is very naive as I have started with C# and .NET just 2 months back. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the absence of the parameterless constructor. Below in your exception there is a line: `Cannot resolve parameter 'Capstone2.Entities.Login login' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Capstone2.Service.Interfaces.ILoginService, Capstone2.Entities.Login)'`

So AutoFac tries to use your constructor, it does find ILoginService, because it was apparently registered with the DI. However the `Login` type was not, therefore AutoFac cannot initialize it and therefore it cannot call your constructor.

You should hide `Login` type behind an interface, register it with the DI (AutoFac), and then it will work. However `Login` is most likely not a service, but a concrete instance of your Login-Data. Then this cannot be passed in the constructor. Login data should be fetched from somewhere else (I cannot tell more without knowing your code), most likely from the `HttpContext` (Principal: `this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User`) by injecting `IHttpContextAccessor`.